# Running embedded VBA module inside Access database via Python

Tags: vba, ms-access, python-3.8

I have a VBA module/script inside Microsoft Access db as seen in the image below.

Normally I just click on green play button and it runs fine. This is just a sample script. The real script has many more queries so running the individual queries through Python is not the option. i.e. I can't just extract out `query2` and run in python.

How do I make the entire module `addSample()` run via Python however.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a socket for communication between Access and your Python script. For Python, this is trivial to open and use a socket. For Access, you could use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670391/vba-socket-connection-in-office-2010) in your VBA code. Once the socket is connected, just pass strings as command/status messages between the programs.